# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable error on pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, nonetype

I get the NoneType Error at the temp_df.plot() line. Same happens with the autocprrelation plot as well as when fitting the model. As you can see I tried dropping na and there are no empty or missing values in the series. Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import to_datetime, DataFrame
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
from matplotlib import pyplot
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
path ='C:\\Users\o.ojuko\OneDrive - apeiron GmbH\Data\\'
stundentlichDF = pd.read_excel(path+'Database.xlsx',sheet_name='StündlichDaily',parse_dates=['Date'])
#Exclude 1st 4 months of 2021
forecastDF = stundentlichDF.drop(stundentlichDF[(stundentlichDF['Calendar Year']==2021) & (stundentlichDF['Month'].isin(["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr"]))].index)
#forecastDF = stundentlichDF.loc[~((stundentlichDF['Calendar Year'] == 2021) & (stundentlichDF['Month'].isin(["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr"]))),:]
forecastDF = forecastDF.loc[~((forecastDF['Working Year'] == 2020) & (forecastDF['Month'] == "Dec")),:]
#Select data
for x in forecastDF['StoreName'].unique():
    print(x)
    for y in forecastDF['Weekday'].unique():
        print(y)
        for z in forecastDF['Stunde'].unique():
            print(z)
            temp_df = forecastDF.loc[((forecastDF['StoreName'] == x) & (forecastDF['Weekday'] == y) & (forecastDF['Stunde'] == z)),:]
            #Forecasting
            temp_df= temp_df[['Date','Aufträge']]
            #temp_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['Date'])
            temp_df = pd.Series(temp_df['Aufträge'].values, index=temp_df['Date'])
            print(temp_df)
            temp_df =temp_df.dropna()
            print(type(temp_df))
            temp_df.plot()
            autocorrelation_plot(temp_df)
            df_log = np.log(temp_df)
            pyplot.plot(df_log)
            model = ARIMA(temp_df,order=(5,1,0))
            model_fit = model.fit()
            print(model_fit.summary())
            residuals = DataFrame(model_fit.resid)
            residuals.plot()
            pyplot.show()
            #density plot of residuals
            residuals.plot(kind='kde')
            pyplot.show()
            print(residuals.describe())
            a = "Pause"
```

Comment: I know you've included your code but are you **100% sure** the dropna line isn't actually `temp_df=temp_df.dropna(inplace=True)`, with the inplace argument specified? Given you create that df right before the plot, that is really the only possible way you'd get such an error.

Comment: If you use `inplace=True` you should not assign it again, as it returns nothing. @ALollz

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Dego is right, reassigning it returns a NoneType. not reassigning it now returns 'TypeError: 'numpy.dtype[bool_]' object is not callable'. Seems very similar to the original error.

Comment: Fitting the model actually returns the original NoneType error. That is despite using inplace without reassigning.

Comment: This only happens when I debug. When I run the program, it isn't a problem at all. So when debugging, I use a try, except block to avoid the error.

Comment: Answer could be located in this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72202926/during-debugging-pandas-gave-an-error-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-cal