# During debugging, pandas gave an error: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Tags: pandas, debugging, pycharm

I have a record table.

```
   data  stage  epoch
0     0  train      0
1     1  valid      1
2     2  train      0
3     3  valid      1
4     4  train      2
5     5  valid      3
```

I want to separate this table by “train and ”valid“ starting from the last 0 in the ”epoch“. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    

class SL(object):

    def select(self, df):
        df_train = df[df["stage"] == "train"]
        df_valid = df[df["stage"] == "valid"]

        index_zero = np.where(df["epoch"].values == 0)[0][-1]
        df_train = df_train.loc[index_zero:, :]
        df_valid = df_valid.loc[index_zero:, :]
        print(df_train,"\n", df_valid)

df = pd.DataFrame({"data":range(6), "stage":["train","valid","train", "valid","train","valid"], "epoch":[0,1,0,1,2,3]})
SL().select(df)
```

when I run it directly, it works fine,

```
 data  stage  epoch
2     2  train      0
4     4  train      2 

    data  stage  epoch
3     3  valid      1
5     5  valid      3
```

but when I debug with Pycharm, `df_valid = df_valid.loc[index_zero:, :]` always gives an error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug that only occurs during debugging of certain Numpy-backed code on Python 3.10. The error originates in Cython, and has been recently been fixed. A couple of days ago Numpy [1.22.4](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.22.4) has been released, built with a new Cython, to also solve the problem in Numpy. Now you might still have to rebuild Pandas and Scikit-learn to use the most recent Numpy.

You can do this with a command similar to:

```bash
CFLAGS="-DCYTHON_FAST_PYCALL=0" pip install --force-reinstall --no-binary numpy,scikit-learn,pandas scikit-learn pandas numpy scipy
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can first filter out the rows before the last 0 and then split using `groupby`:

```
s = df['epoch'].eq(0).cumsum()
d = {k: g for k,g in df[s.eq(s.iloc[-1])].groupby(df['stage'])}
```

output:

```
{'train':    data  stage  epoch
 2     2  train      0
 4     4  train      2,
 'valid':    data  stage  epoch
 3     3  valid      1
 5     5  valid      3}
```